# What's the best method?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any difference between this two indexes, and if so, which one is better to use? Would like some informarion about the performance and difference if any.

```
$array[$data]
$array["$data"]
```

Thanks in advance!

*edit; just came across `$array["{$data}"]`, any information about that one?

Comment: There's no reason to use the second.

Comment: $array[$data] means array variable $array with index as value of variable $data, while $array["$data"] means array variable $array with index as $data

Comment: @saveATcode: Now that's where you're wrong... `$array['$data'];` would imply `$data` is a key string, but `$arry["$data"]` uses _the value of `$data`_, but cast to string, just like `echo "$foo bar";` will print the value of `$foo`, unlike `echo '$foo bar';`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Hmm, interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd go for the first version, because of clarity. PHP will sort it out for you:

```
$a = range(1,10);
$data = 2;
echo $a[$data];//3
$b = array('foo' => 'bar');
echo $b[$data];//notice undefined offset, echoes nothing!
$data = 'foo';
echo $b[$data];//echo bar
```

A couple of other reasons: `'$data'` !== `"$data"`, because there is a difference between single and double quotes. So the second way is slightly more error-prone.
Using arrays is messy:

```
$a[$data['key']];//is clear: use value of $data -> key
```

compared to:

```
$a["{$data[key]}"];
//or
$a["{$data['key']}"];
```

There's more room for personal preference. Though that might *seem* like a good thing, but when working in a team, using SVC systems like Git, this soon proves to be a pain... believe you me!

Note:

On your edit to your question (the `"{$var}"`). This is called [*Complex (curly) syntax*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), and it's there to avoid abiguity:

```
echo "some string with $an[array][value]";
```

What should the parser do? should it echo:

```
"some string with <value of$an>[array][value]";
```

treating the array key accessors as string constants, or did you mean:

```
"some string with <$an[array][value]>";
```

It could echo: *"some string with foobar"* as well as *"some string with array[array][value]"*, that's why you group the expression:

```
echo "some string with {$an[array][value]}";
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Appreciate it, learned something new today :) Will accept answer within 10 minutes.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting: You're welcome, I've added a bit on the `"{$var}"` notation

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes allow variables to work exactly as they are, so in your particular case, there is no difference.

However, using actual text would make a very big difference in an associative array:

```
$array[fluffeh]; // Will not work
$array['fluffeh']; will reference the key called fluffeh in the array.
```

Variables inside double quotes will work like they are just part of a string. however, sticking a variable inside single quotes won't work as exected.

```
$var='fluffeh';
$array[$var];   // Will find the element 'fluffeh'
$array["$var"]; // Will find the element 'fluffeh'
$array['$var']; // Will try to find an element called '$var'
```

Comment: using `$array[fluffeh]` will work, but trigger a notice

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Anything that triggers a notice in my books means it doesn't work :) I know that PHP assumes constants as variables if a constant of that name doesn't exist, but it's not really working.. is it :)

Comment: Of course, you're right, if you read some of my answers on code-review, you'll soon find out I loathe code that issues notices, but for fairness/completeness' sake, I added the comment. That, and the use of non-quoted string constants wasn't the question ;)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem All good, but I a one of those "If it ain't purring, it ain't working..." folks. Anything that throws warnings and has a general hissy fit when being executed - in my books, that's code that isn't working. Fair comment though. +1